# Linux Script & MySql operations not working, When Invoked from other script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

I have written this piece of code to insert rows into table if not there, else, update the 'cnt' by one more. This works very well, when I invoke it from command line, when I invoke it from shell script, this does not work.

```
file=$1
echo "$0: Path to store $file" ;
res=`mysql -e "use spam_sending_scripts; select * from spamemailcount where path = '$file' limit 0,1"`
echo $res
if [ -z "$res" ]
then
    mysql -e "use spam_sending_scripts; INSERT INTO spamemailcount (cnt,path) VALUES(1,'$file');"
    echo "Inserting into DB $file , res $res" ;
    exit ;
fi
mysql -e "use spam_sending_scripts; update spamemailcount SET cnt=cnt+1 where path = \"$file\"" ;
echo "Updating into DB $file" ;
#mysql -e "use spam_sending_scripts; select * from spamemailcount" >> /var/log/sendmail.log
mysql -e "use spam_sending_scripts; select * from spamemailcount"
```

`root@server [/home]# insertintodb.sh AAA`  ==> This is working fine.

When I invoke from the other script, this file is executed, But Insert does not work.

I invoke it like: `/home/insertintodb.sh $path`

The `$path` variable is getting passed to `insertintodb.sh` correctly.

I am getting the following Error:

```
++ mysql -e 'use spam_sending_scripts; select * from spamemailcount where path = '\''hackerssquadron.com/wp-comments-post.php'\'' limit 0,1'
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: What about `/home/insertintodb.sh "$path"`?

Comment: Invoke your script in debug mode: `bash -x /home/insertintodb.sh "$path"`

Comment: Do you invoke from a different user maybe? Because you always need the file `~/.my.cnf` with `[mysql]` configuration for username and password etc, if you don't have default login/server in the global config.

Answer (score 4):

Use `chmod` command to make it executable

```
chmod ugo+x insertinodb.sh
```

Then try calling it same as @Jdamian suggested

```
bash -x /home/insertintodb.sh "$path"
```

Comment: `chmod 777` to make it executable ..... ?? -100 if I could just for that. This will make the file readable & writable for everyone on the system, is that really what we want? No. To make it executable, use `chmod a+x`, or maybe `chmod 755` (`750` might be better, since you may not want this world-readable, either).

Comment: Already mentioned bro @DanFromGermany it was just due to i didn't given much attention. Sorry

Comment: Thanks for your input, I call this script from command line
bash -x insertintodb.sh "about.in/wp-comments-post.php" ==> working fine. I am able to debug the script.

/bin/bash -x /home/insertintodb.sh $fpath >> $LOGFILE (Like this i invoke from another script, But does not work)

Comment: Jdamian & Skynet Thanks for your input. I am getting the following Error. 
++ mysql -e 'use spam_sending_scripts; select * from spamemailcount where path = '\''hackerssquadron.com/wp-comments-post.php'\'' limit 0,1'
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: @Mani try this `bash -x /home/insertintodb.sh $fpath >> $LOGFILE`

Comment: Please, update the manin question text in order to include the reported error.

Comment: Follow this syntax exactly @Mani `mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -h HOSTNAMEORIP DATABASENAME `

Answer (score 2):

This problem is solved.

1. When I try to invoke the script from the command line, It is working fine. 
   Reason => I am running this script as a root. So no problem
2. When I invoke the script using another shell script, It is not working.
   Reason: This main script is being invoked by apache and It is trying to access the root DB, so permission denied.

Based on input from Skynet & Jdamian, I am able to debug it and resolve it.

Thank you very much for support, As usual this is one of the best place to get the technical queries resolved quickly by experts.